# Get xml children without replacing html entities in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have this code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
$strXml = '
<root>
<kid><div>ABC&#8226;&#62;</div></kid>
<kid2>DEF</kid2>
</root>';   

$objXml = new SimpleXMLElement($strXml);
$arrNodes = $objXml->xpath('/root/*');
foreach($arrNodes as $objNode) {
    /* @var $objNode SimpleXMLElement */
    echo $objNode->asXML(); 
}
```

The code extracts the first children of the root and displays the content. The problem is the html entities are converted to characters. Is there any way the code output the initial XML content without any conversion ?

Comment: Are they really converted, or are you viewing the output in a browser? Look at the page source if you are...

Comment: Running your code, I see `#&62;` is output as `&lt;`.

Comment: @Michael: Are you sure? I see `&gt;`.

Comment: I edited the code so you can understand better, it's even worse, for some entities is converted to their name entity, and for bullet to it's character.

Comment: @ComFreek Yes you're right, it was `&gt;` Mistyped in the comment.

Comment: Try using [XMLReader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php), SimpleXML is kind of Mickey Mouse.

Comment: @GGG that won't help, the behaviour is identical.

Comment: @salathe don't make me pull out my console ;) wait, maybe I am thinking of DOM XML... better pull it out after all.

Comment: @GGG DOM will behave in the same way too.

Comment: @salathe now I'm determined to make this work, this is crazy.

Comment: I'm not seeing the crazy, but it looks like at least three people do. Good luck on your quest, @GGG ! :)

Comment: @salathe the issue is numeric entities are always defined, named ones have to be defined by a DTD or similar for XML parser to recognize them.

Comment: @GGG be careful not to confuse *(numeric) character references* with entity references, they share the `&…;` syntax but are not the same. Character references are not entity references, they don't get substituted with another declared value, they are simply alternative representations of characters.

Comment: @salathe you're absolutely right, I was typing without thinking. I meant character references, not "numeric entities" which means nothing. What I was trying to say is character references are always valid, entity references are only valid if defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way the code output the initial XML content without any conversion ?

No.

<sup>Aside: Why do you care? They're the same character.</sup>

Comment: You care if you have a client that desires the same output in the end, even if technically it's the same.

Comment: I really wouldn't, but that's just me. Either way you have your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML / DOMDocument / etc will always convert these entities as numbered entities are not valid XML.

So either:

- Epic search and replace.
- Or perhaps fix whatever is generating the XML?

Comment: Numeric entities are valid in XML.

Comment: According to SimpleXML etc it is not... you are technically correct though... http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets

Comment: @IngmarBoddington can you find any bug reports or discussions about this? It seems like a really weird behavior to me and I can't find much about it at all. It seems to affect *all* of the various PHP XML stuff (that I know of).

Comment: Does seem strange. May be a solution using `html_entity_decode` with the new `ENT_XML1` flag: http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: If this was combined with `filter_var($value, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH);` which returns numbered entities.

Comment: Yeah, but you'd have to do it after the fact... internally it's just a regular character until it gets converted to text from xml

Answer (score 0):

This strikes me as a really strange behavior, and I'm not having any luck searching for information.

It seems to affect all of the relevant [XML stuff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php). It's also worth noting that the characters are stored as regular characters once the XML is parsed:

```
php > print_r($objXml);
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [kid] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [div] => ABC•>
        )

    [kid2] => DEF
)
```

...they're written as entities when the XML is converted to text. I'm guessing everything is using the same internal routine to convert to text.

If you really need this feature, you can create your own function to escape the characters, something like this:

```
// function to escape some utf8 characters with xml character reference 
function xmlCharEncode($string) {

  $out = '';

  $len = mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8');

  for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {

    $char = mb_substr($string, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');

    $convmap = array(
      60,  60, 0, 0xffff, // <
      62,  62, 0, 0xffff, // >
      38,  38, 0, 0xffff, // ampersand
      // you may want to filter quotes or other characters here
      127, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff, // everything after basic latin
    );

    $enc = mb_encode_numericentity($char, $convmap, 'UTF-8');

    $out .= $enc;

  }

  return $out;

}
```

... and then use XMLReader and XMLWriter to write the XML using your custom character escaping routine:

```
// read and write your xml string

$r = new XMLReader();
$w = new XMLWriter();
$r->xml($strXml);
$w->openMemory();

while($r->read()) {

  switch ($r->nodeType) {

    // write elements, attributes, and text nodes

    case XMLReader::ELEMENT:
      $w->startElement($r->name);
      while ($r->moveToNextAttribute()) {
        echo $w->outputMemory(true);
        $w->writeAttribute($r->name, $r->value);
      }
      break;

    case XMLReader::END_ELEMENT:
      $w->endElement();
      break;

    case XMLReader::TEXT:
      $w->writeRaw(xmlCharEncode($r->value)); // the magic happens here
      break;

  }

  echo $w->outputMemory(true);

}
```

I'm not really convinced this is worth the trouble, but at least you have an idea of what kind of things can be done to get this working.

This will work with your original example, by the way.